# How to handle NullPointerException while reading, filtering and counting the lines of CSV files using SparkSession?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I'm trying to read the CSV files stored on HDFS using `sparkSession` and count the number of lines and print the value on the console. However, I'm constantly getting `NullPointerException` while calculating the count. Below is the code snippet,

```
val validEmployeeIds = Set("12345", "6789")

val count =  sparkSession
    .read
    .option("escape", "\"")
    .option("quote", "\"")
    .csv(inputPath)
    .filter(row => validEmployeeIds.contains(row.getString(0)))
    .distinct()
    .count()

println(count)
```

I'm getting an NPE exactly at `.filter` condition. If I remove `.filter` in the code, it runs fine and prints the count. How can I handle this NPE?

The `inputPath` is a folder that contains contains multiple CSV files. Each CSV file has two columns, one represents Id and other represents name of the employee. A sample CSV extract is below:

```
12345,Employee1
AA888,Employee2
```

I'm using Spark version 2.3.1.

Comment: Can you add an extract from csv file you are trying to read ?

Comment: Added the sample csv extract details

Answer (score 0):

Try using `isin` function.

```
import spark.implicits._

val validEmployeeIds = List("12345", "6789")

val df =  // Read CSV

df.filter('_c0.isin(validEmployeeIds:_*)).distinct().count()
```